# angular 2 select control without ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, optimization

When creating a select control, with options that may be pulled from a database, it seems customary to put an ngFor on the template side to render the options.

What I want to do is instead have a loop on the component side that builds a string with the options:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    this.selectOptions += "<option value=" + i + ">" + i + "</option> ";
}
```

Then in the template side of something like this:

```
<select>
    {{selectOptions}}
</select>
```

The reason I want to do this is I have some nested loops in a complex UI, and several selects that have the same options. Once rendered the options do not change.

I want to get rid of all the ngFors that are running in order to try to speed up my UI. There are other things I need to do as well, but this is something that I think could help. Then the loops for the options only have to run 1 time instead of over and over.

Comment: SO is awesome. Look at the same answer you received within 4 minutes :)

Comment: Does this work in Angular 4?  Using the above code to build out the options and [innerHTML]="selectOptions" when I inspect the element this is what it shows:  <select _ngcontent-c2="">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 </select>

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `[innerHTML]` along with the `DomSanitizer`:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpkk4v?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

**Component:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  options = '<option value=1>1</option><option value=1>1</option>';
  optionsHTML: any;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.optionsHTML = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.options);
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<select [innerHTML]="optionsHTML"></select>
```

**Note:**

You need to sanitize the HTML in order for angular to render it, otherwise angular will remove the HTML and all you get is a string rendering `<select>11</select>`

Comment: Its amazing how it takes some complex things to do something so simple :)

Comment: Angular can sometimes over-complicate things, however in this case it's an additional security measure from angular to avoid html/script injection.

Answer (score 1):

Untested but I think you could use `innerHTML` like this:

```
<select [innerHTML]="selectOptions"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding) it seems that

```
<select [innerHTML]="selectOptions"></select>
```

.. is what you're looking for. It is also said to work currently in version `5.0.2`

Comment: Please see my commment above that is below my OP, does this work in Angular 4?

Answer (score 0):

Every one is telling you to use the `[innerHTML]` attribute : **they're wrong**.

And you are not going on the right path : **you should use iterations in your HTML, not in your component's logic**.

### Why is that ?

Because when you use `[innerHTML]`, you actually create just a string, **that isn't related in any way to Angular**. Furthermore, reading your code will become difficult, because you will have to switch from your HTML to your TS to see what you're doing.

### The solution

You said you had several complicated loops and once set, the options should not move ? That's perfect for Angular !

You can create a new component that will handle your selects :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-select',
  template: `
  <select [(ngModel)]="mySelect" (change)="change.emit(mySelect)" *ngIf="options">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{ option }}</option>
  </select>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./my-select.scss']
})
export class MySelectComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() options: any[];
  @Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  mySelect: any; 

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('options are ' + this.options);
    this.mySelect = this.options[0];
  }
}
```

Now, in your other components, you can simply do

```
<app-my-select [options]="yourOptions" (change)="doSomething($event)"></app-my-select>
```